# Нужно ли выделить "злодея"?

Tags: пунктуация

Это его рук дело, его злодея и только его!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Это его рук дело, его, злодея, и только его!***

1) Всегда обособляется приложение, отнесенное **к личному местоимению:** его, злодея.

Правило Розенталя : http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

8. Всегда обособляется приложение при личном местоимении: Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином?

2) В то же время в предложении очень много запятых, что затрудняет понимание текста.

Вариант редактирования: ***Это его, злодея, рук дело, его и только его!***

Правило для выражения ***его и только его*** :

3. Если оборот с повторяющимся словом присоединяется союзом и, то перед союзом ставится запятая, а при подчеркивании присоединяемой конструкции — тире: Суд руководствуется законом, и только законом; Ты, и только ты можешь сделать это; 
   **Но (без интонации присоединения):** Через три точки, не принадлежащие одной прямой, проходит **одна и только одна** плоскость.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105